# How to create Angular 6 singleton services in specific feature modules

Tags: angular, angular6

Summarize of what I'd like to achieve:

I want to be able to use singleton service in 2 different lazy loaded feature modules. This service should not be available from other lazy/eagerly loaded feature modules. So somehow, I'd like to scope the service. As far as I know, in angular, I can register the services globally among all the modules, or in case of lazy loading modules, these services will have new instances if I don't use the provideIn: 'root', or classic old forRoot logic.

Here you can find a prepared github project: https://github.com/Norby125/angular-singleton

If you check the structure, technically I have a common module called shell, which provides services to every feature module, so these services are globally available for all the feature modules. I have 2 feature area called sub-app1 and sub-app2. In sub-app1 I want to have the same instance of all core module services, but I want to make these services unavailable for sub-app2 modules. It is important that all the features within areas have to be lazy loaded, like feature1 and feature2 modules.

I would appreciate any guidance in this.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines for asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I adjusted a question a little bit, I hope it is better now

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the service in the feature module, the scope will be restricted to that featured module.

In order to hide some services from the feature modules, you could create another module that would work as main, and load the feature modules as siblings. something like this:

```
app.module
- main app
- feature module 1
- feature module 2
```

And provide the necessary events to allow the communication between main and feature modules, a.k.a. Subjects and BehaviorSubject

btw, stackblitz is a nice and easy way to demonstrate scenarios ;) look at this one not 100% related to your question: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-services-di-playground

Comment: "When you provide the service in the feature module, the scope will be restricted to that featured module." Yes, in case of lazy loading modules, so when I have multiple lazy loaded modules, and provide them the service, it will create multiple service instances which I want to avoid. I need a singleton service among multiple lazy loaded feature modules, and hide it from any other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just provide the service only in that feature module? Or if you only really need it in 1 component within the module, have the component have a `providers: []`

Comment: You misunderstood me. I want to have the same instance of a specific service (shared) between lazy loaded modules.

Comment: ahhh that would be a problem :) maybe you can use a BehaviorSubject in the main to keep what you need available to the lazyloaded elements, and subscribe to it in the lazy loaded modules. I am pretty sure that injected services from the main won't be propagated to the lazyloaded modules